# JavaScript -What's with the #2 in this program

Tags: javascript

According to the tutorial I am reading, the program below displays "Hello Ima Reader."

I have one question about this program. Why does it, in its final line, insert a "2" into `alert(name[2])`?

When the function is called in the second last line, it only passes "name", but when the alert is run it uses a "2". I'm assuming that 2 refers to the length of name, but is it necessary? If so, Why?

```
function makeHello(name) {
   name[name.length] = "Hello" + name [0] + " " + name[1];
}

var name = new Array ('Ima', 'Reader');
makeHello(name);
alert(name[2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `var name = new Array ('Ima', 'Reader');` creates an array called `name` with element `0` set to `"Ima"` and element `1` set to `"Reader"`.

The next line, `makeHello(name);`, invokes the `makeHello` function which creates an element `2` in the `name` array set to `"Hello Ima Reader"`.

The last line, `alert(name[2]);` merely displays the element `2` that was created by the `makeHello` function.

Comment: thank you. looking at the second line of the program, is the purpose of the code "name.length" to set the position in the array of the new element "Hello Ima Reader" by taking the length (which was 2) of the original array "name"? Is that why name.length is in [] brackets?

Answer (score 3):

makeHello adds a new item to the array "name".  This new item is the word "Hello" plus the first and second item in the array.  Therefore, makeHello[2] returns "Hello Ima Reader".

makeHello is trying to add the new item to the end of the array.  If you don't know the size of the array then you can call name.length to return a value which will symbolize the position of the new/last item.

Answer (score 2):

This code is doing some convoluted stuff. The `makeHello(name)` call passes a 2-element array to the `makeHello()` function. At this point, `hello` looks like this:

```
['Ima', 'Reader']
```

The `makeHello` function reads the first two elements from the array that's passed in, but does not change them, and uses them to insert a new element at the end of the array. When `makeHello` is done, `hello` looks like this:

```
['Ima', 'Reader', 'Hello Ima Reader']
```

The `alert()` call simply grabs the last element from the `hello` array.

---

Overall, this code uses fairly poor style, and I might recommend using a better tutorial to learn JavaScript from. The [Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) is a top-notch resource for all things JS.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 refers to the 3rd position in the name array, which was set in the makeHello function.